# How to display decimal in specific format in Jackson (for JSON)

Tags: json, spring, jackson

Suppose I have an object with

```
private Double test;

// Need specific output in JSON via Jackson: test = 24.6000
```

When output to JSON via Jackson, I get `24.6`, but I need the exact 4-decimal output as in the example. Does Jackson allow this?

For example, for Dates, we found a way to force `MM/dd/yyyy:`

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy")
       Date myDate;
```

We need something similar for Decimal formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this is to use custom json serializer and specify in `@JsonSerialize`.

```
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomDoubleSerializer.class)
public Double getAmount()

public class CustomDoubleSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Double> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Double value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonGenerationException {
        if (null == value) {
            jgen.writeNull();
        } else {
            final String pattern = ".####";
            final DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
            final String output = myFormatter.format(value);
            jgen.writeNumber(output);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks so there is no out-of-the-box Jackson annotation, in other words? For most cases there are.

Comment: I don't think there is. But it would be a nice addition since this is a very common use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.RawValue:

```
BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal(new BigInteger("246000"), 4);
RawValue rv = new RawValue(d.toPlainString());
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectNode output = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
output.putRawValue("decimal_value", rv);
System.out.println(output.toPrettyString());
//output is:
//{
//  "decimal_value" : 24.6000
//}
```